# No results when query within foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search, foreach

I'm trying to match users with a certain description in one table to a general search description in another table. I have a foreach that contains the general descriptions and created a query within the foreach hoping to pull out the user that best fits that general description.

Problem is I'm not getting any results when I echo out the `username`. I get results when I echo out result['title'].

```
if (empty($errors)){
  $results = search_results($keywords);
  $results_num = count($results);

  echo '<p><strong style ="font-size:145%;font-family:georgia;"> Titles: </strong></p> ';

  foreach ($results as $result){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, title from clothing 
    WHERE description LIKE '%$results%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $username=$row['username'];                     
    $title=$row['title'];
    echo $username;
    }
    echo '<p> <strong>',$result['title'],'</strong> </p>';
  }

}
```

I would be very grateful to know why my user is not getting echoed out. Also any programming tips would be greatly appreciated for I am always learning and I want to always find ways to improve.

Comment: Why don't you see if that query returns anything. As in, run it against the database in an SQL tool.

Comment: What does $result return on foreach(...) ?

Comment: are you sure your query returns >= 1rows?

Comment: In your query, you mean to use the `foreach` variable `$result`, not `$results` as you have: `LIKE '%$results%'"`

Comment: $result returns titles like it's supposed to @Robert

Comment: Even so, my username still does not get echo'd @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace $results with $result in your query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username, title from clothing WHERE description LIKE '%$result%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set one check (with error message)if count equals to 0 ..
And LIKE clause value must be result not results

```
if (empty($errors)){
                $results = search_results($keywords);
                $results_num = count($results);

                if($results_num==0) {
                    echo "NO RESULTS MESSAGE !!!"; 
                }
                else{

                    echo '<p><strong style ="font-size:145%;font-family:georgia;"> Titles: </strong></p> ';

                    foreach ($results as $result){
                      $query = mysql_query("SELECT username, title from clothing WHERE description LIKE '%$result%'");
                      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        $username=$row['username'];                     
                        $title=$row['title'];
                        echo $username;
                      }
                      echo '<p> <strong>',$result['title'],'</strong> </p>';
                    }
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, title from clothing WHERE description LIKE '%$results%'
```

`$results`,it seems to be an array.I think you have to use `$result` here.